# View taking the place/position of another view in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter, listview-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a list of images that I'm showing, using universal image loader, now I'm trying to put an ad in between in position 4, but this ad is replacing the image in that position.. When looking at the positions and urls everything seems to be ok. Is there something wrong with the custom adapter? Or is it possible to do something in the xml?

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println(position+" "+urls.get(position));
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            switch (type)
            {
                case TILBUD:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_row, null);
                    holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_row);
                    imageLoader.displayImage(urls.get(position), holder.imageView, options);
                    break;
                case AD_SPACE_1:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_space_row_1, null);
                    adSpace1 = (AdSpace)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ad_row_1);
                    adSpace1.setSID(returnSID(store, "ad1"));
                    adSpace1.setAdEventListener(adEventListener);
                    adSpace1.setAdErrorEventListener(adErrorListener);
                    adSpace1.setAdAnimationEventListener(adAnimationListener);
                    adSpace1.setAdMediaEventListener(adMediaEventListener);
                    holder.adSpace1 = adSpace1;
                    adSpace1.runAd();
                    break;
                case AD_SPACE_2:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_space_row_2, null);
                    adSpace2 = (AdSpace)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ad_row_2);
                    adSpace2.setSID(returnSID(store, "ad2"));
                    adSpace2.setAdEventListener(adEventListener);
                    adSpace2.setAdErrorEventListener(adErrorListener);
                    adSpace2.setAdAnimationEventListener(adAnimationListener);
                    adSpace2.setAdMediaEventListener(adMediaEventListener);
                    holder.adSpace2 = adSpace2;
                    adSpace2.runAd();
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }


}
public static class ViewHolder 
{
    public ImageView imageView;
    public AdSpace adSpace1, adSpace2;
}
```

Comment: Try to define one layout after your image in xml and base on position like (position%4==0) try Ad to this layout in getView().

Comment: @Haresh tried this, did not change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with the position of the ads, needed +1 on ad1 and +2 on ad2.